# Need to check in multiple files and change to major versions

Tags: check-in, version

A coworker uploaded a ton of files to sharepoint now they all need to be checked in and changed to major versions. I am helping her but really hoping there is an easier way to do both at the same time than going through each individually.

Comment: You can write CSOM C# console application to automate  check in of files

Comment: what version of sharepoint you are using? may be use the content & structure appoaach to do it.http://wordimpress.com/check-in-or-out-multiple-files-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

If they are new files that all need to be checked in, go to your document library settings and under Permissions and Management look for 'Manage files which have no checked in version'.  You can take ownership and check them in in bulk from here.